# WiFi internet sharing from iMac unreliable

Tags: macos, wifi, imac, internet-sharing, ethernet

I want to share an internet connection that my iMac gets via Ethernet over WiFi, so that I can connect to it with other devices.

I went into System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing on the iMac and turned it on for sharing Ethernet over WiFi, but I'm finding it unreliable.

Particularly, the internet connection of devices connected to the WiFi created by the iMac seem to randomly die, even though the iMac still connects to the internet just fine. Note that the WiFi created by the iMac itself is always visible, it just doesn't seem to provide access to the internet after a while, even though it should, since the iMac sharing the connection can access the internet just fine.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you talking of MacOS X 10.7.4?

Comment: @danielAzuelos: yes I believe that is what's installed on the iMac, can't check now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer the question but it did fix my problem.

I simply used the Connectify Widows program instead, which works SO MUCH BETTER. I've been using it for about a week now without a single glitch.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience *Internet Sharing* is not, and has never been, as reliable as it should. Connection coming back and forth is a usual behavior of the service, heavily depending on the usage of the machine which is sharing the internet connection.

[Apparently](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3940663?tstart=0), updating to 10.7.4 makes things even worse.

Comment: Well in that case, is there another, more reliable way to share the connection?

Comment: The obvious solution is through a router, of course, but through a computer, this way is the only way I can imagine.

Comment: hmm, well that is not what I hoped to hear :D

Comment: I have a 4 MBP & 3 iPhone network running regularly through an iMac configured as a network applicative firewall without a glitch thanks to InternetSharing... until the 10.7.4 outcome :[.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem of reliably sharing an ethernet connection. This is 10.12.6, but this behavior has been the same through several system upgrades. The "arrow" wifi icon will revert to the light gray bars and the wifi signal stops connecting. One partial fix I found was to change the wifi channel to try a less crowded radio space. This helped for a while on 2.4 GHz, but seems better broadcasting at 5 GHz. Still turns off intermittently though, just not as bad. Perhaps the issue has to do with interference?